# Connect multiple database in one controller cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hello I am new to cakephp 2. I want to know, how to connect to database in one controller and loop for each. Please help me with details.

I have already set the following in the database config:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db_one',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $database2 = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db_announcement',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should research bit more in google before asking question here.

Anyways, CakePHP takes default database connection which is there in database.php in core folder, so all your queries which you execute in the database which is defined in default vairable in database.php and if you want to connect multiple database than you can try something like this.

In your database configuration file:

```
public $database2 = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '*******',
        'database' => '*****',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

And in your controller you can have connection in this way:

```
        $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('user');
        $list = $db->rawQuery('your query'); or customized CakePHP queries can work here too
```

I hope you will get your answer from this.

Thanks
                $i=0;
                $total=$list->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: how about foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

instead of `getDataSource` method I would suggest to use `$this->ModelName->setDataSource('mongo');`

E.g If you want to fetch the data from User model of 'mongo' database source , which you have mentioned in database.php, then to set that it would look like.

> $this->User->setDataSource('mongo')

in database.php you are having following code

```
public $mongo = array(
        'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'mongo_data',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead